# How to make an object property of type array optional in javascript?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo, rendering

I'm testing a react native expo app that access the device contacts.

on an emulator with only 5 contacts, everything was Ok. But when I Was testing on my physical android device, I got this error 'TypeError: TaskQueue: Error with task : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'contact.phoneNumbers[0]')'.

here is how I access the contacts in the App component.

```
useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;
        const fetchAllContacts = async () => {
            const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
            if (status === "granted") {
                const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({});

                if (isMounted) {
                    setContacts(data);
                }
            }
        };

        fetchAllContacts();

        return () => {
            isMounted = false;
        };
    }, []);

    const renderItem = ({ item }) => <ContactCard contact={item} />;


    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Contacts App</Text>
            </View>
            <Text style={{ padding: 20, fontWeight: "600", color: "#aaa" }}>All Contacts</Text>

            <FlatList
                data={contacts.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(contact) => contact.id}
                style={{ padding: 8 }}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

here is the contact card component where I am trying to access the contact first phoneNumber from the phoneNumbers array.

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import Contact from "./Contact";

const ContactCard = ({ contact }) => {
    const phoneNumberWithoutSpaces = contact?.phoneNumbers[0].number.toString().replace(/\s+/g, "");

    const firstLetter = phoneNumberWithoutSpaces.slice(0, 1);

    return <Contact contact={contact} colour="yellow" network="MTN" />;
}
```

Which I also pass to the Contact component

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function Contact({ contact, network, colour }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <View style={[styles.contactIcon, { backgroundColor: colour }]}>
                <Text style={styles.iconText}>{contact?.name[0]}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{contact?.name}</Text>
                <View style={styles.subTitle}>
                    <Text style={styles.phone}>{contact?.phoneNumbers[0].number}</Text>

                    <Text style={{ color: colour, fontWeight: "500" }}>{network}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

so please how do I solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing `name` 
 which is a string value type

```
<Text style={styles.iconText}>{contact?.name[0]}</Text>
```

```
export default function Contact({ contact, network, colour }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.card}>
            <View style={[styles.contactIcon, { backgroundColor: colour }]}>
                <Text style={styles.iconText}>{contact?.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={styles.name}>{contact?.name}</Text>
                <View style={styles.subTitle}>
                    <Text style={styles.phone}>{contact?.phoneNumbers[0].number}</Text>

                    <Text style={{ color: colour, fontWeight: "500" }}>{network}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: In the name property, I'm accessing the first letter of the string.   But that's not the issue, the main problem is in the phone numbers array. I'm thinking of how to make optional like 'contact?.name'

Comment: ok got it @PaulAjonye when you are getting any item from an array you can check like
array.length>0?array[0]?.name:""